# Terraform- Azure IPgroups tags update for no reason

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm using Azure and terraform to deploy some ipgroups.
I'm using loops and modules to deploy my ipgroups and everything is deploying correctly.
But when I do a terraform plan after my deployment, terraforms says it will update my ipgroups tags.

And of course, I changed nothing between 2 terraform runs :

```
 # module.CreateAzureRmIpGroup.azurerm_ip_group.ipgroup[0] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_ip_group" "ipgroup" {
        id                  = "xxx"
        name                = "ipgr-all-allservers-weeu-001"
      ~ tags                = {
          + "Area"           = "westeurope"
          + "Business_Line"  = "bb"
          + "Creation_Date"  = "10/02/2021"
          + "Environment"    = "hub"
          + "Gdpr"           = "2"
          + "Owner"          = "aa"
          + "Ressource_Type" = "ipgroup"
          - "area"           = "westeurope" -> null
          - "business_Line"  = "bb" -> null
          - "creation_Date"  = "10/02/2021" -> null
          - "environment"    = "hub" -> null
          - "gdpr"           = "2" -> null
          - "owner"          = "aa" -> null
          - "ressource_Type" = "ipgroup" -> null
        }
        # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

As you can see , It will pass my tags to null and pass from null to my old tags. Just the tags , not even the ip of ipgroups...
I create the tags like I do for others services and I only have a problem with ipgroups tags.....(no pb with networks/firewalls/vpn)

Here's my ipgroup resource :

```
 resource "azurerm_ip_group" "ipgroup" {
 count               = length(var.ipgroup)
 name                = "ipgr-${var.ipgroup[count.index]["ipgr_content"]}-${var.ipgroup[count.index] 
 ["ipgr_loc"]}-${var.ipgroup[count.index]["id"]}"
 location            = var.ipgroup_location
 resource_group_name = var.ipgroup_rg_name
 cidrs = split(",", var.ipgroup[count.index]["ipgr_cidr"])
 tags = {
    
    Owner        =  var.ipgroup[count.index]["owner"]
    Business_Line = var.ipgroup[count.index]["business_line"]
    Area         = var.ipgroup[count.index]["area"]
    Environment = var.ipgroup[count.index]["environment"]
    Creation_Date = var.ipgroup[count.index]["creation_date"]
    Gdpr = var.ipgroup[count.index]["gdpr"]
    Ressource_Type = "ipgroup"
    }}
```

And this is a tfvars example :

```
ipgroup = [{
ipgr_content = "all-allservers"
ipgr_loc = "weeu"
id = "001"
ipgr_cidr = "10.0.0.0/20"

owner = "aa"
business_line ="bb"
area = "westeurope"
environment = "hub"
creation_date = "10/02/2021"
gdpr = "2"
},]
```

I tried to comment my tags but even with that terraform still update the ressource's tag.

I don't know if there is a real impact to have an update everytime (I will have to do an apply if I have to add more ipgroups). I don't want to take the risk when I will use these ipgroups in my firewall.

Comment: Looks like tags having case changed is what triggers the update. You provide uppercase-first-letter, Azure persists them as lowercase-first. It seems it happens with other resources too: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/6367. I suggest you post to that thread. In the meantime you can rename tags to be lowercase-first if that works for you.

Comment: Yes you are right, if I change to lowercase it's works , but this means that I will have a tag named "owner" just for ipgroups and a second one named "Owner" for the others

Comment: I suggest you post a comment on Github, to bring it to awareness and (hopefully) make the fix coming sooner. Cheers.